# How to autofill id & password on safari without clicking?

Tags: safari, password

How to make the id & password automatically filled without click to fill?

When I use Chrome, Chrome autofill id & password so I can just click the Login button.
but on Safari, I have to select which id & password I want before clicking Login.

Comment: Chrome autofill does not work in the way you describe. It makes me pick a login before filling it.

Comment: Look at KeePassXC with the browser plugin (open source). If you have just one password, it will work like you describe, but if you have more than one, it will make you pick.